# How can I get solution of this system of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$
\begin{cases}
x + 2y - 2z = 3 \\
3x - y + z = 1 \\
-x + 5y - 5z = 5
\end{cases}
$$

It's a shame but I don't know why I can't figure out the solution of this system of linear equations.

I did some sort of substitution and elimination but I can't find neither $y$ nor $z$.

because when I plug $x$ back in any equation which its value is $\frac{5}{7}$ the equation has then no variables left.

Any solution or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Since this is tagged "linear algebra", I assume you are familiar with [Gauss-Jordan elimination](http://pages.pacificcoast.net/~cazelais/251/gauss-jordan.pdf)?

Comment: So should I use Gauss-Jordan elimination or there is other way to do it?

Comment: Don't consider as a shame that you haven't solved your system. It is a peculiar system with rank 2 (its determinant is 0). Thus you will not have a unique solution, it will depend on an arbitrary parameter as given for example by @Mattos

Comment: That said, forming the augmented matrix and reducing it to row echelon form is a general way to solve such problems.  If you have a reason *not* to perform elimination or elementary row operations, you should have included that in the body of your Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to work with the *augmented matrix*, and put the matrix in *reduced row echelon form*:
\begin{align}
&\begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1&2&-2&3\\3&-1&1&1\\
-1&5&-5&5
\end{array}\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1&2&-2&3\\0&-7&7&-8\\
0&7&-7&5
\end{array}\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1&2&-2&3\\0&-7&7&-8\\
0&0&0&0
\end{array}\end{bmatrix}\\[2ex]
{}\rightsquigarrow&\begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1&2&-2&3\\0&1&-1&\frac87\\
0&0&0&0
\end{array}\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1&0&0&\frac 57\\0&1&-1&\frac87\\
0&0&0&0
\end{array}\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
whence the solutions $\;x=\frac57,\quad y=z+\frac87$, or as a parametric equation of a straight line:
$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac 57\\\frac87\\0\end{bmatrix}+t\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: I do appreciate that mate, thanks!!

Comment: Of course, arbitrary parameter $t$ could be called ... $z$ :)